# Gitlab prometheus error after upgrade with apt-get upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ruby, gitlab, prometheus

after upgrading my gitlab from 10.9.2 to version 10.10 on my Ubuntu 18.04 it was not possible for the apt-get upgrade process to end successfully. It ended with following message:

```
Ensuring Prometheus is updated:Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `load'
     9: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/bin/omnibus-ctl:31:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:746:in `run'
     7: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:197:in `block in add_command'
     6: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/prometheus-upgrade.rb:45:in `block in load_file'
     5: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/lib/gitlab_ctl/prometheus_upgrade.rb:40:in `backup_data'
     4: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:520:in `mv'
     3: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1555:in `fu_each_src_dest'
     2: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
     1: from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1557:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:525:in `block in mv': File exists - /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data_tmp/data (Errno::EEXIST)
Ensuring Prometheus is updated: NOT OK
Error ensuring Prometheus is updated. Please check the logs
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ce (--configure):
 installed gitlab-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I restart my gitlab with gitlab-ctl restart it is working fine, but when I try apt-get upgrade again, it want to finish the installation and stops again with same message.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `File exists - /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data_tmp/data (Errno::EEXIST)`.
The error message is mentioned in a [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4522) about another problem. You could move that file `/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data_tmp/data` to another location or remove it altogether (you would lose data that way) and hope that the update will run through.

Comment: this was not successful, file was automatically created again and same error again - but thanks for the idea!

Comment: I'm sorry to read that. I guess it is best for you to file a issue with [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues).